# Is there a much simpler or shorter version of this code using a button

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm sorry if the title is vague. It's because I don't know exactly what it is called.

I am creating a program for a school project and I'm trying to figure out a shorter version of a code that I already got.

The interface looks like this:
[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0IMF.png)

The other parts of the program are not really necessary to put on here. They just input texts/strings in the first row textfields and shifts down one column every time new info is put in the first row.

The buttons on the right (the ones with the [x]) are the ones that are coded. They remove the text/string in the row next to them and shifts up the texts from below (if there are any) by one column.
The code for the first button is such:

```
    CC01.setText(CC02.getText());
    SC01.setText(SC02.getText());
    SU01.setText(SU02.getText());
    SD01.setText(SD02.getText());
    SR01.setText(SR02.getText());
    
    CC02.setText(CC03.getText());
    SC02.setText(SC03.getText());
    SU02.setText(SU03.getText());
    SD02.setText(SD03.getText());
    SR02.setText(SR03.getText());
    
    CC03.setText(CC04.getText());
    SC03.setText(SC04.getText());
    SU03.setText(SU04.getText());
    SD03.setText(SD04.getText());
    SR03.setText(SR04.getText());
    
    CC04.setText(CC05.getText());
    SC04.setText(SC05.getText());
    SU04.setText(SU05.getText());
    SD04.setText(SD05.getText());
    SR04.setText(SR05.getText());
    
    CC05.setText(CC06.getText());
    SC05.setText(SC06.getText());
    SU05.setText(SU06.getText());
    SD05.setText(SD06.getText());
    SR05.setText(SR06.getText());
    
    CC06.setText(CC07.getText());
    SC06.setText(SC07.getText());
    SU06.setText(SU07.getText());
    SD06.setText(SD07.getText());
    SR06.setText(SR07.getText());
    
    CC07.setText(CC08.getText());
    SC07.setText(SC08.getText());
    SU07.setText(SU08.getText());
    SD07.setText(SD08.getText());
    SR07.setText(SR08.getText());
    
    CC08.setText(CC09.getText());
    SC08.setText(SC09.getText());
    SU08.setText(SU09.getText());
    SD08.setText(SD09.getText());
    SR08.setText(SR09.getText());
    
    CC09.setText(CC10.getText());
    SC09.setText(SC10.getText());
    SU09.setText(SU10.getText());
    SD09.setText(SD10.getText());
    SR09.setText(SR10.getText());
    
    CC10.setText("");
    SC10.setText("");
    SU10.setText("");
    SD10.setText("");
    SR10.setText("");
```

So, yes, I have ten of these buttons. And the code for each button reduces by one 5-line code. For example, Button1's code is the one you see up top, then Button2's code starts from the [CC02...], the Button3 starts from [CC03], etc.

I think I used the brute force method of this code which I don't think is efficient and makes my code too long (the code for the ten [x] buttons alone is around 400 lines).

I asking of there is a much shorter way of doing this method.

Thanks.

Comment: Read more about tables in Java

Comment: Well, tables will definitely make the code easier and I already thought of it. I used it on my earlier projects.

Comment: But I need to use jTextfields because the project that I am making is a computerized recreation of a form. The form is usually hand-written so I 'm trying to recreate it in an interface form to be able to finish filling up the form faster.

Comment: Put your text fields in 2D lists or arrays. Then iterate through these lists/arrays.